# Install C# library without the Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, visual-studio-express, package-managers

Is there any way to install C# libraries other than using the Package Manager Console? I want to use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook) but I'm using Visual Studio Express for WP and I don't have the PMC. I found [this guide on nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console), but I'm going to have to do it some other way.

Any ideas?

Comment: by installing them, you mean adding the libraries to GAC?

Comment: I want to add the library to my current project so I can use it.

Comment: Are you using VS2012 express or 2010 express?

Comment: 2010. Is this available in VS2012? If so I could always upgrade

Comment: Yes it does. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned in README.md file on how to download Facebook C# SDK `.dll` files without using NuGet Package Manager Console at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk

> Binaries for Facebook C# SDK are only distributed via nuget. For those using older versions of Visual Studio that does not support NuGet Package Manager, please download the command line version of NuGet.exe (http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939) and run the following command.
>
> ```
> nuget install Facebook
> ```
>
> If you would like to get an older version of the the binaries please use the following command.
>
> ```
> nuget install Facebook -v 5.4.1
> ```

Update:
Yo can download version directly from the browser by navigating to http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Facebook/6.4.0 rename the .nupkg to .zip and extract it using your favorite zip program.

Answer (score 2):

There is a alternative open-source IDE  sharpDevelop.
It can add packages to your projects. 
It works with the visual Studio files!

In the latest version the plugin is even independent from wether the plugin for visual studio is installed or not!
[Nuget in SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/01/23/NuGetSupportInSharpDevelop.aspx)

PS: It does have some limitations in comparison with the plugin from VS, complexe packages will fail to do everything that they are supposed to do.  Interactions with the IDE for instance will likely fail. ( So MVC 3 model generation will not work if you install that package with SharpDevelop)

Answer (score 0):

VS 2012 has the option, under Tools->Library Package Manager.

Comment: Remember it is a RC version at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the [Facebook SDK source from github](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/) and add a reference to the sdk project from your solution.

Or just build the libraries from the Facebook SDK solution and reference them in your project.