# Package Manager Console does not find an existing package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget-package

I am testing logging in via Facebook on sample project. In order to retrieve the email address of a logged in user from Facebook, I need to install Facebook package as per [the accepted answer in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714500/access-email-address-in-the-oauth-externallogincallback-from-facebook-v2-4-api-i) I try to install the package by trying these two PMC commands

> Install-Package Facebook -Version 7.0.6

or

> Install-Package Facebook

I instead get the following errors respectively (which show the package doesn't exist )

> install-package : Unable to find package 'Facebook'.

and

> Install-Package : Unable to find version '7.0.6' of package 'Facebook'.

However when I use Manage Nuget Packages from Tools Menu and search for Facebook, I get the package. What really is wrong?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036060/install-c-sharp-library-without-the-package-manager-console

Comment: Am using Visual Studio 2013 Community and unlike that post, I have PMC. When I was unable to install through PMC, I just used the Manage Nuget Packages dialog and installed. My question rather is **why is searching for the packages through the PMC command line not returning results when the packages exist?**

Comment: What do you have your package source set to. Needs to be nuget.org to get the facebook SDK

Comment: Try setting Package source to nuget.org and do a search for it. PM> Find-Package facebook

Comment: The command is `Install-Package` though and not `Find-Package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select Package source differently for the GUI and the Console. Try setting Console to `nuget.org` or `all`. 
Then do a search for your package: `PM> Find-Package facebook` and you should get the following results as in the Image below.

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the package source from `nuget.org` to `Microsoft and .Net` and the package installed on a sample project. Seems all you have to do is set package source to All or for this particular case to `Microsoft and .Net`. Thanks.